# Python Social Auth. relate to existing Profiles model

Tags: django, facebook, django-models, python-social-auth

I just included python social auth and added Facebook login. I have a Profile model where I save some user data like "description" and "username".

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    user_des = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    ...
```

How do I relate the user's Facebook account to the existing model, and where do I save that relation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the social auth docs I found that you can specify custom user models using this in your settings.py:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.CustomUser'
```

In your case it will be:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.Profile'
```

The docs I found this on are here:

http://django-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html#custom-user-model

They also include documentation of ORMs here:

http://django-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html#orms

edit:

By default social-auth uses the

```
django.contrib.auth.User
```

model to save users, the documentation can be found here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/

Comment: So, maybe I'm just confused. python-social-auth creates a User model? can I relate my Profile model to that model instead of overriding it?

Comment: Yep! By default it uses the `django.contrib.auth.User` , you don't need to define a custom model.

Comment: @TPOT94, ``SOCIAL_AUTH_USER_MODEL`` is to point to a ``User`` model definition, not a ``Profile``. Profiles are internal to Django. @alejoss, you can relate the profile to the user model created by ``python-social-auth`` by adding a custom function to the pipeline, check the docs at http://psa.matiasaguirre.net/docs/pipeline.html#extending-the-pipeline